# Sublime Text 2 issue with open parenthesis not typing at end of function calls

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I setup Sublime Text 2 with a few packages for Python development. Starting entering some code like:

```
al_filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

When I typed that first '(' nothing happened, it would not type for some reason. Out of a hunch, I typed a [ then hit ( and it worked. So I typed my open/close parens and removed the brackets. I am not sure what's going on, checked the console for errors and it's clean.

Installed Packages

```
Case Conversion
CaseConversion
Cheat Sheets
Clojure
Color Scheme - Default
CSS
D
Default
Diff
Erlang
fnkr-sublimepascal-18483dbc6260
Git
GitGutter
Github Tools
Go
Graphviz
Groovy
Haskell
HTML
Java
JavaScript
Jedi - Python autocompletion
Language - English
LaTeX
Lisp
Lua
Makefile
Markdown
Matlab
Neon Color Scheme
Objective-C
OCaml
Package Control
Pascal
Perl
PHP
Python
PythonTidy
R
Rails
Regular Expressions
RestructuredText
Ruby
Scala
ShellScript
SidebarEnhancements
SQL
Sublime Text 2 Snippets
SublimeCodeIntel
sublime-js-snippets
SublimePythonTidy
SublimeREPL
sublime-text-2-clipboard-history
Sublime-Text-2-Stackoverflow-Plugin
SublimeText-Sublime-Text-2-Snippets
SublimeTODO
sublime-todomanager
TCL
Text
Textile
Theme - Default
Theme - Soda
Theme - Tomorrow
User
Vintage
XML
YAML
ActionScript
All Autocomplete
AppleScript
ASP
AutoHotKey
Batch File
C#
```

Any ideas? I am not new to Sublime Text 2 per se, but I am new to using it as a development environment for python vs just a python syntax-highlighting editor. My google-fu found nothing similar. Thanks for any input on this issue. :)

Comment: Did I ask this in the right stack community?

Comment: Works OK for me. FWIW I don't have a `Jedi - Python autocompletion` package installed, so the regular `Python` must be doing the autocompletion (with no issues).

Comment: I'll remove Jedi and see if that fixes the issue. Thanks for the quick reply and suggestion!

Comment: Disabled Jedi and that fixed the issue. Answer with this suggestion and I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks! Maybe an upvote on my question too? :)

Comment: I know you have an answer already, but thought I'd give some debug tips. As there is a command running, rather than the default `insert_snippet`, try entering `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the ST console to see what's executing. If you can identify the command great, if not, you can use something like https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts to determine which plugin is running the command.

Comment: @skuroda Thanks! It's responses like this that make stackexchange/overflow such a great community and my favorite resources for those real "nuts & bolts" experiences that new programmers like myself cannot find elsewhere. Thanks for taking the time to share this wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 works OK in this respect for me.

While I didn't compare *every* package you listed as installed to my own list, I noticed that you had one called`Jedi - Python autocompletion`which I don't — so that might be a good place to start.

Here's a complete list of the packages I do have installed on my **Windows** system:

```
ActionScript                            Markdown
AppleScript                             Matlab
ASP                                     Objective-C
Batch File                              OCaml
C#                                      Package Control
C++                                     Perl
Clojure                                 PHP
Color Scheme - Default                  Python
CSS                                     Python Pep8 Lint
D                                       R
Default                                 Rails
Diff                                    Regular Expressions
Erlang                                  RestructuredText
Go                                      Ruby
Graphviz                                Scala
Groovy                                  ShellScript
Haskell                                 SQL
HTML                                    TCL
Java                                    Text
JavaScript                              Textile
Language - English                      Theme - Default
LaTeX                                   User
Lisp                                    Vintage
Lua                                     XML
Makefile                                YAML
```

Comment: Now if I can just find out why Jedi does this. Would you mind sharing your python development package list? I am new to python as a whole and in developing it via ST2, but ST2 is my editor of choice for everything else. It would be nice to know what someone with more experience is using. I just added some packages I found on some websites of guys who use ST2 and ST3 as their Editor/IDE of choice.

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the list. I see a few I might need to investigate for use in the future. Thanks again for the help and answering my question. It perplexed me for hours.

One more question: Are you using a Mac or PC for development? Just curious if some of these packages are more Mac or PC centric for development. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For Mac Users:

Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Package Settings -> Jedi -> Keymap -> Default ->
Change line **#12**:

`{"command": "sublime_jedi_params_autocomplete", "keys": ["("],`

to

`{"command": "sublime_jedi_params_autocomplete", "keys": ["super+ctrl+j"],`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. It was due to Jedi Package. Just disabling and enabling the package solved the issue.

Open package control (Preferences -> package control)

> Disable Package: Jedi
>
> Enable Package: Jedi

**Finding the root cause:**

With sublime console, you can easily identify the culprit for this kind of issues.
Open sublime console (view -> show console) and enter the below command.

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

It shows the log for all the commands you are typing in sublime. In my case if I enter '(' it was referring something related to Jedi Auto complete package. So I got to know that issue is with Jedi Package.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
go to `Preference-> Package Control`

or

<kbd>ctrl + shift + p</kbd>

**Step 2:**
Select or search,

**Disable pacakge**

and then,

**Step 3**:
Search package called Jedi - python auto completion.
that's all your issue resolved.

Reason is,

Jedi python override open paranthesis command with its own keyword, `sublime_jedi_params_autocomplete`

you can trace it by <kbd>ctrl+`</kbd> and enter **sublime.log_commands (True)**